Scrolling on ttk.Combobox with CTkScrollableFrame underneath
Scrolling on Combobox droplist from tkinter.ttk module raises exception when there's CTkScrollableFrame underneath.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1948, in call
return self.func(*args)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_scrollable_frame.py", line 248, in _mouse_wheel_all
if self.check_if_master_is_canvas(event.widget):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users[user]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_scrollable_frame.py", line 280, in check_if_master_is_canvas
elif widget.master is not None:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'master'


Sample code:
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import customtkinter as ctk

def display_combobox(root):
    sample_values = ['test' for _ in range(30)]
    combo_box = ttk.Combobox(root, values=sample_values)
    combo_box.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.3)

def display_scrollable(root):
    scrollabe_frame = ctk.CTkScrollableFrame(root, label_text='text', width=150)
    scrollabe_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.6)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('500x500')
    display_combobox(root)
    display_scrollable(root)

    root.mainloop()


If you look into the source code of CTkScrollableFrame, the following binding will be executed when creating the instance:
self.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", self._mouse_wheel_all, add="+")

So mouse-wheel event will also be triggered when scrolling the combobox drop-down list using mouse-wheel.
However event.widget is a string for this case which causes the exception.  From the error traceback, the exception is raised inside CTkScrollableFrame.check_if_master_is_canvas().
So suggest to create a custom class that inherits from CTkScrollableFrame and override the above function:
class MyScrollableFrame(ctk.CTkScrollableFrame):
    def check_if_master_is_canvas(self, widget):
        # call the original method if widget is a tkinter widget, not string
        if isinstance(widget, tk.Widget):
            return super().check_if_master_is_canvas(widget)
        return False

Then use this custom class instead of CTkScrollableFrame:
def display_scrollable(root):
    scrollabe_frame = MyScrollableFrame(root, label_text='text', width=150)
    scrollabe_frame.place(anchor='center', relx=0.5, rely=0.6)


Mouswheel on the CTkScrollableFrame passes <class 'tkinter.Canvas'> into the binding, scrolling on the Combobox entry passes a <class 'tkinter.ttk.Combobox'> but scrolling on the Listbox elements of the Combobox passes <class 'str'>. @acw1668 solution prevents the callback of the scrollable frame for the last case.
